# how can I check modelview stack depth in OpenGL 1.0 (on Android)?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I write a program for Android using OpenGL 1.0. I want to check what is modelview stack depth. I try to use glGetIntegerv, but in GL10 class I can't see GL_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH constant - even though in GL11 class there is one. So, is it possible to check modelview stack depth in OpenGL 1.0 on Android?

Answer (score 0):

It is because in GL10 class this constant is called GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH.